# Programmatically changing the User's account image in OSX

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, user-accounts

Is there some way I can programmatically change the users account image on OSX?
I know I can retrieve it, but can it be changed like apple does on the account page in the settings app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Address Book framework. You need to use the `me` method to get the record for the current user, and then the `setImageData:` method to set the user's image:

```
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>

@implementation YourClass
- (void)setUserImage:(NSImage*)anImage
{
    ABPerson* me = [[ABAddressBook addressBook] me];
    [me setImageData:[anImage TIFFRepresentation]];
}
@end
```

There's more detail [here in the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/AddressBook/Tasks/AccessingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001023-103617).

Comment: FWIW, `-[ABAddressBook me]` appears to return `nil` if you haven't explicitly added an entry for yourself in Address Book. (And thus this won't work in that case).

Answer (score 3):

You can path out to a file and merge it with the current record using the /usr/bin/dsimport command, which could be run from a NSTask. Here is an example of how to do so with BASH as root, this could be done with passed credentials as well

```
    export OsVersion=`sw_vers -productVersion | awk -F"." '{print $2;exit}'`
    declare -x UserPicture="/path/to/$UserName.jpg"
    # Add the LDAP picture to the user record if dsimport is avaiable 10.6+
    if [ -f "$UserPicture" ] ; then
        # On 10.6 and higher this works
        if [ "$OsVersion" -ge "6" ] ; then
            declare -x Mappings='0x0A 0x5C 0x3A 0x2C'
            declare -x Attributes='dsRecTypeStandard:Users 2 dsAttrTypeStandard:RecordName externalbinary:dsAttrTypeStandard:JPEGPhoto'
            declare -x PictureImport="/Library/Caches/$UserName.picture.dsimport"
            printf "%s %s \n%s:%s" "$Mappings" "$Attributes" "$UserName" "$UserPicture" >"$PictureImport"
            # Check to see if the username is correct and import picture
            if id "$UserName" &>/dev/null ; then
                # No credentials passed as we are running as root
                dsimport -g  "$PictureImport" /Local/Default M &&
                    echo "Successfully imported users picture."
            fi
        fi
    fi
```

[Gist of this code](https://gist.github.com/2138160)

Comment: Why do this when you can just use the Address Book framework? It's two lines of code and doesn't require any command-line fu.

Comment: Because if you haven't explicitly added an entry for yourself in Address Book, then the AB based way won't work.

Answer (score 2):

I am almost certain that you can do this through the OpenDirectory interface.  See this guide:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/Open_Directory/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000917

Basically you have to open a Open Directory Node (say the /Search node), and then find the ODRecord for your user, then use:

```
setValue:forAttribute:error
```

on the ODRecord to set the JPEGPhoto attribute.

If you query using dscl from the command line for this attribute you will see the attribute's value:

```
dscl /Search read /Users/luser JPEGPhoto
```

I believe the dscl tool uses the Open Directory framework (or the older/harder to use/deprecated directory service framework) to read and write attributes to user records.  You can read and write any other attribute using this tool and the associated framework.  I don't see any reason the JPEGPhoto would be any different.

The /Search node MIGHT be read only (since it is kind of a meta node).  Not really sure.  You might have to explicitly open the appropriate node (for example the /Local/Default node) before you can write to the record:

```
dscl /Local/Default read /Users/luser JPEGPhoto
```